# SQL selecting spatial points

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I am trying to select a spatial point in SQL so that I can receive the latitude and coordinate of the point in the most simple form possible.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT AsText(`coordinates`) FROM table
```

This returns something along the lines of:

```
POINT(53.432985 -1.357258)
```

Are there any other spatial functions that will allow me to return these as two seperate values or at least make them a little easier to perform something like substr on them?

Ideally I'd like it to return two values, a latitude value and a longitude value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the geospatial way to retrieve latitude/longitude from a POINT type, assuming that coordinates is stored as a POINT type. X will return the latitude and Y the longitude.

```
SELECT X(coordinates),Y(coordinates) FROM table
```

Comment: As the Question is tagged with mysql i would like to mention the equivalent solution for mysql:
SELECT ST_X(coordinates),ST_Y(coordinates) FROM weather;

Answer (score 0):

I assume your geometry field is called coordinates?

```
SELECT location.STY as Lat, location.STX as Lon from yourTableName
```

If it's a geography datatype try

```
SELECT location.Lat as Lat, location.Long as Lon from yourTablename
```